# Developing a desktop/tablet app with Python

Tags: python, android

Is it possible to use the keyboard library to create a desktop/tablet application for collecting statistical events from a sports match?

I want to develop a tool that will enable me to collect statistics on sporting events during the match. My idea is to assign a precise action to a virtual keyboard (for example, a shot for the letter Q, a pass for the letter W, a loss of the ball for the letter E, etc.). I'd also like to be able to collect these statistics for both teams in the match, for example by assigning a switch team function to the tab key. I know it's possible to use the keyboard library to assign commands to keyboard keys, but is it possible to use this code to develop such a tool?

Comment: I'm betting that anything is possible, but that doesn't help you to solve the problem.  No way to tell how intensive the work would be, regardless of language.